# В чем разница между обращениями a[s] и (a.find(s))->second?

Tags: stl, c++, c++11

```
map<string, int> a;
string s("asd");
int i=1;
a.insert(map::make_value(s,i));
```

В чем разница между обращениями `a[s]` и `(a.find(s))->second`? Можно ли вместо

```
a.insert(map::make_value(s,i));
```

использовать

```
a[s]=i;
```

Comment: Это понятно... я про разницу между `a[s]` и `(a.find(s))->second` при обращении... например вот вывожу

`cout << a[s]`

я так понимаю может быть ошибка, если элемента с таким ключом не будет в `map`, и обязательно нужно проверять 

`if ( a.find(s) != a.end() ) { ...`
?

Comment: Ой... 

там нет map::make_value, нужно пользоваться make_pair(...

пользовался http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb385468.aspx , а надо http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/81ac0zkz.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator[]` добавляет пару ключ-значение в `map`, если пара с указанным ключом отсутствует.
`find` ничего не добавляет, а просто возвращает итератор, предоставляющий доступ к нужной паре.
Что касается второй части вопроса,

```
a[s]=i;
```

то вам никто не запрещает так писать. Лично мне больше нравится добавлять пары в map явно.

P.S.: если не важен порядок следования ключей, пользуйтесь более быстрым `unordered_map`.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на второй вопрос вытекает из ответа на первый. При отсутствии значения по ключу через operator[], новый айтем будет создаваться автоматически. А find же в этом случае вернет after-end итератор, со всеми вытекающими при попытке доступа через pair->second.

Answer (score 1):

> (a.find(s))->second

Ждите беды. Перед тем, как обратиться к second, обязательно проверьте валидность итератора, полученного из метода find.

```
map<string, int>::iterator it_found = a.find(s);
if(it_found != a.end()) {
    it_found->second;
}
```